# SIFT descriptor returns NoneType in OpenCV when used in a loop

Tags: python, opencv, sift

I have some images stored in a Pandas dataframe and I'm trying to compute their SIFT features as follows:

```
for image in df['images']:
    sift = cv2.xfeatures2d.SIFT_create()
    (kps, descs) = sift.detectAndCompute(image, None)
    print descs == None
    # Do something with the descriptors
```

For a particular image this loop gives 'NoneType' to the 'descs' variable when run in a loop. However when I run the code step by step individually for that image it runs without any issues. I'm not able to figure out the reason.

Comment: Please show both the code that works, and the code that doesn't, including the image loading. How do you verify is the same image which is causing the problem?